# What is the right mypy annotation for collections.Counter?

Tags: python, mypy, python-3.10

## My Problem

I am writing a Python function with a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) that counts strings and prints the total number of strings counted. I tried annotating the function in various ways. but all failed the mypy test:

### Code

```py
from collections import Counter
import typing

def f1(c : Counter[str]) -> None:
    print(c.total())

def f2(c : Counter) -> None:
    print(c.total())

def f3(c : Counter[str, int]) -> None:
    print(c.total())


c : Counter = Counter()
c.update(['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'])

f1(c)
f2(c)
f3(c)
```

### Errors

```sh
use_counter.py:5: error: "Counter[str]" has no attribute "total"
use_counter.py:8: error: "Counter[Any]" has no attribute "total"
use_counter.py:10: error: "Counter" expects 1 type argument, but 2 given
use_counter.py:11: error: "Counter[Any]" has no attribute "total"
```

## What Have I Tried

Various ways to annotate `Counter` (in `f1`, `f2`, and `f3`) and googling for answers.

## My Question

What's the right way to annotate a [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) so that its methods (like `total`) are recognized by mypy?

Comment: `Counter.total` is new in Python 3.10. What version of `mypy` are you using?

Comment: I suspect `f1` is correct (`f2` is as well, though not as specific as it could be), and that the problem is your version of `mypy`, not the annotation.

Comment: apparently [mypy](https://pypi.org/project/mypy/) doesn't support py3.10 yet